Assembly code compiles but does not display output in asmloader
I am working on a project using asmloader, and I have encountered an issue. My program compiles without any errors, but when I run it in asmloader, it does not display the expected results. Here is the code I am using:
%ifdef COMMENT

; Program to perform long addition of numbers a and b
; Displays the result in the format:
; a = 9237
; b = 1267
;    1 11
;    9237
;  + 1267
;  ------
;  10504
; Requires asmloader

%endif

         [bits 32]

; esp -> [ret]  ; ret - return address to asmloader

a        equ 9237
b        equ 1267

         mov eax, a      ; move value of a to eax
         mov ebx, b      ; move value of b to ebx
         xor ecx, ecx    ; clear carry
         xor edi, edi    ; clear result
         mov esi, 1      ; set multiplier to 1 (units)

.next_digit:
         mov edx, eax    ; copy value of eax to edx
         and edx, 0xF    ; extract last digit of a (4-bit mask)

         mov edi, ebx    ; copy value of ebx to edi
         and edi, 0xF    ; extract last digit of b (4-bit mask)
         add edx, edi    ; add digits of a and b
         add edx, ecx    ; add carry

         cmp edx, 10
         jl .no_carry    ; if no carry, go to .no_carry
         sub edx, 10
         mov ecx, 1      ; set carry to 1
         jmp .store_digit

.no_carry:
         xor ecx, ecx    ; clear carry

.store_digit:
         imul edx, esi   ; multiply digit by multiplier (units, tens, hundreds...)
         add edi, edx    ; add digit to result

         shr eax, 4      ; shift right by 4 bits (one digit less)
         shr ebx, 4      ; shift right by 4 bits (one digit less)
         imul esi, esi, 10 ; go to next digit (multiplier * 10)

         cmp eax, 0
         jne .next_digit ; if a != 0, repeat loop
         cmp ebx, 0
         jne .next_digit ; if b != 0, repeat loop

         ; Final result in edi

         mov eax, a      ; move value of a to eax (for display)
         mov ebx, b      ; move value of b to ebx (for display)
         mov ecx, edi    ; move result to ecx

raddr:

; esp -> [ret]

         push ecx        ; result
         push ebx        ; b
         push eax        ; a
         push ebx        ; b
         push eax        ; a

; esp -> [a][b][a][b][result][ret]

         call getaddr
format:
         db "a = %d", 0xA, 0
         db "b = %d", 0xA, 0
         db "    %4d", 0xA, 0
         db "+ %4d", 0xA, 0
         db "------", 0xA, 0
         db "  %5d", 0xA, 0
getaddr:

; esp -> [format][a][b][a][b][result][ret]

         call [ebx+3*4]  ; printf(format, a, b, a, b, result)
         add esp, 5*4    ; esp = esp + 20

; esp -> [ret]

         push 0          ; esp -> [0][ret]
         call [ebx+0*4]  ; exit(0)

%ifdef COMMENT
;  a = 9237
;  b = 1267

;    1  1  1
;    9237
;  + 1267
;  ------
;  10504
%endif

; asmloader API
;
; ESP points to a valid stack
; Function arguments are pushed onto the stack
; EBX contains a pointer to the API table
;
; call [ebx + FUNCTION_NUMBER*4] ; call an API function
;
; FUNCTION_NUMBER:
;
; 0 - exit
; 1 - putchar
; 2 - getchar
; 3 - printf
; 4 - scanf
;
; The return value of the function is in EAX.
; After calling a function, arguments are removed from the stack.
;
; https://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=387

This code compiles successfully but does not display any results when run in asmloader. I expect it to perform long addition and display the formatted output.
I have also tried a simpler version of the code which works but does not handle carry properly for long addition:
%ifdef COMMENT

; Program to perform long addition of numbers a and b
; Displays the result in the format "a = %d\nb = %d\n    %d\n+   %d\n------\n    %d\n"
; Requires asmloader

%endif

         [bits 32]

; esp -> [ret]  ; ret - return address to asmloader

a        equ 9237
b        equ 1267

         mov eax, a  ; eax = a
         mov ecx, b  ; ecx = b

         add eax, ecx  ; eax = eax + ecx (result in eax)

raddr:

; esp -> [ret]

         push eax     ; result
         push ecx     ; b
         push a       ; a
         push ecx     ; b
         push a       ; a

; esp -> [a][b][a][b][result][ret]

         call getaddr
format:
         db "a = %d", 0xA,
         db "b = %d", 0xA,
         db "  %4d", 0xA,
         db "+ %4d", 0xA,
         db "------", 0xA,
         db "  %5d", 0xA, 0
getaddr:

; esp -> [format][a][b][a][b][result][ret]

         call [ebx+3*4]  ; printf(format, a, b, a, b, result)
         add esp, 5*4    ; esp = esp + 20

; esp -> [ret]

         push 0          ; esp -> [0][ret]
         call [ebx+0*4]  ; exit(0)

%ifdef COMMENT
;  a = 9237
;  b = 1267

;    1 11
;    9237
;  + 1267
;  ------
;  10504
%endif

; asmloader API
;
; ESP points to a valid stack
; Function arguments are pushed onto the stack
; EBX contains a pointer to the API table
;
; call [ebx + FUNCTION_NUMBER*4] ; call an API function
;
; FUNCTION_NUMBER:
;
; 0 - exit
; 1 - putchar
; 2 - getchar
; 3 - printf
; 4 - scanf
;
; The return value of the function is in EAX.
; After calling a function, arguments are removed from the stack.
;
; https://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=387

Could you please help me understand why the first code does not display the results even though it compiles successfully? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
What did you try and what were you expecting?
I tried writing an assembly program to perform long addition of two numbers and display the result in a formatted output using asmloader. Here are the steps I followed and the two versions of the code I tried:

Initial Code:
This code is supposed to perform long addition of two numbers a and b, handling carries, and displaying the result. It compiles successfully but does not produce any output in asmloader.
%ifdef COMMENT

; Program to perform long addition of numbers a and b
; Displays the result in the format:
; a = 9237
; b = 1267
;    1 11
;    9237
;  + 1267
;  ------
;  10504
; Requires asmloader

%endif

         [bits 32]

; esp -> [ret]  ; ret - return address to asmloader

a        equ 9237
b        equ 1267

         mov eax, a      ; move value of a to eax
         mov ebx, b      ; move value of b to ebx
         xor ecx, ecx    ; clear carry
         xor edi, edi    ; clear result
         mov esi, 1      ; set multiplier to 1 (units)

.next_digit:
         mov edx, eax    ; copy value of eax to edx
         and edx, 0xF    ; extract last digit of a (4-bit mask)

         mov edi, ebx    ; copy value of ebx to edi
         and edi, 0xF    ; extract last digit of b (4-bit mask)
         add edx, edi    ; add digits of a and b
         add edx, ecx    ; add carry

         cmp edx, 10
         jl .no_carry    ; if no carry, go to .no_carry
         sub edx, 10
         mov ecx, 1      ; set carry to 1
         jmp .store_digit

.no_carry:
         xor ecx, ecx    ; clear carry

.store_digit:
         imul edx, esi   ; multiply digit by multiplier (units, tens, hundreds...)
         add edi, edx    ; add digit to result

         shr eax, 4      ; shift right by 4 bits (one digit less)
         shr ebx, 4      ; shift right by 4 bits (one digit less)
         imul esi, esi, 10 ; go to next digit (multiplier * 10)

         cmp eax, 0
         jne .next_digit ; if a != 0, repeat loop
         cmp ebx, 0
         jne .next_digit ; if b != 0, repeat loop

         ; Final result in edi

         mov eax, a      ; move value of a to eax (for display)
         mov ebx, b      ; move value of b to ebx (for display)
         mov ecx, edi    ; move result to ecx

raddr:

; esp -> [ret]

         push ecx        ; result
         push ebx        ; b
         push eax        ; a
         push ebx        ; b
         push eax        ; a

; esp -> [a][b][a][b][result][ret]

         call getaddr
format:
         db "a = %d", 0xA, 0
         db "b = %d", 0xA, 0
         db "    %4d", 0xA, 0
         db "+ %4d", 0xA, 0
         db "------", 0xA, 0
         db "  %5d", 0xA, 0
getaddr:

; esp -> [format][a][b][a][b][result][ret]

         call [ebx+3*4]  ; printf(format, a, b, a, b, result)
         add esp, 5*4    ; esp = esp + 20

; esp -> [ret]

         push 0          ; esp -> [0][ret]
         call [ebx+0*4]  ; exit(0)

%ifdef COMMENT
;  a = 9237
;  b = 1267

;    1  1  1
;    9237
;  + 1267
;  ------
;  10504
%endif

; asmloader API
;
; ESP points to a valid stack
; Function arguments are pushed onto the stack
; EBX contains a pointer to the API table
;
; call [ebx + FUNCTION_NUMBER*4] ; call an API function
;
; FUNCTION_NUMBER:
;
; 0 - exit
; 1 - putchar
; 2 - getchar
; 3 - printf
; 4 - scanf
;
; The return value of the function is in EAX.
; After calling a function, arguments are removed from the stack.
;
; https://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=387


Simpler Code:
This simpler version works and displays the result but does not handle carry properly for long addition.
%ifdef COMMENT

; Program to perform long addition of numbers a and b
; Displays the result in the format "a = %d\nb = %d\n    %d\n+   %d\n------\n    %d\n"
; Requires asmloader

%endif

         [bits 32]

; esp -> [ret]  ; ret - return address to asmloader

a        equ 9237
b        equ 1267

         mov eax, a  ; eax = a
         mov ecx, b  ; ecx = b

         add eax, ecx  ; eax = eax + ecx (result in eax)

raddr:

; esp -> [ret]

         push eax     ; result
         push ecx     ; b
         push a       ; a
         push ecx     ; b
         push a       ; a

; esp -> [a][b][a][b][result][ret]

         call getaddr
format:
         db "a = %d", 0xA,
         db "b = %d", 0xA,
         db "  %4d", 0xA,
         db "+ %4d", 0xA,
         db "------", 0xA,
         db "  %5d", 0xA, 0
getaddr:

; esp -> [format][a][b][a][b][result][ret]

         call [ebx+3*4]  ; printf(format, a, b, a, b, result)
         add esp, 5*4    ; esp = esp + 20

; esp -> [ret]

         push 0          ; esp -> [0][ret]
         call [ebx+0*4]  ; exit(0)

%ifdef COMMENT
;  a = 9237
;  b = 1267

;    1 11
;    9237
;  + 1267
;  ------
;  10504
%endif

; asmloader API
;
; ESP points to a valid stack
; Function arguments are pushed onto the stack
; EBX contains a pointer to the API table
;
; call [ebx + FUNCTION_NUMBER*4] ; call an API function
;
; FUNCTION_NUMBER:
;
; 0 - exit
; 1 - putchar
; 2 - getchar
; 3 - printf
; 4 - scanf
;
; The return value of the function is in EAX.
; After calling a function, arguments are removed from the stack.
;
; https://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=387



What I Expected
I expected the first version of the code to perform long addition with proper handling of carry for each digit and display the result in a formatted output using printf. The output should show the intermediate steps of addition, including the carried digits.
Problem
Despite the code compiling successfully, there is no output when running it in asmloader. I have confirmed that the printf function is being called correctly, and the format string is defined properly.
Could anyone help me understand why the first code does not display the results and suggest any fixes?
Thank you!

I don't know asmloader but it's very strange how call [ebx+3*4] is supposed to be printf with ebx just set to b.

Yeah, that seems to be your problem. asmloader passes in the function table in ebx but you overwrite it by the time you try to use it. Notice your working code does not overwrite ebx. If you wish to use ebx then save and restore it, or move the pointer to a different register.

I changed what you said but it's still clean when calling:
https://pastebin.com/LvQ3Bqpy

Line 42 is xor ebx, ebx that will zero it. Do not modify ebx.
